# Neo4J IndexProvider is deprecated

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

The project https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/tree/gh-pages/language-guides/java/spring-data-neo4j produces a warning:
Class 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.index.IndexProvider' is marked deprecated 
I use Spring Boot. The managed version for spring-data-neo4j is 3.2.2.RELEASE
Does anybody know how this deprecation can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is intentional, as the "manual" index APIs are scheduled to go away in Neo4j 3.0 this is a **hint** that using the manual indexes will need to change then.

Comment: Thanks, Michael! Probably we have a slightly different understanding of "deprecated". With a deprecation there should always be an alternative given, that is supposed to be available when the deprecated API goes away. In a new project, where I have the freedom to change as much as I like, I always try to substitute deprecated APIs immediately. If possible I would not like to have any deprecation warning in productive code. Anyway, I understand that there will be an alternative in 3.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Hunger pointed out this deprecation can be ignored. Wit Neo4J 3.0 there will be an alternative available.